# Processing three Database Operations In Parallel

Tags: c#, async-await, entity-framework-core

I am still getting up to speed on async/await, and I ask this mainly as a learning question.

I have this method which simply creates three objects in a row.

The question is, are these actually being processed in parallel? Meaning mulitple threads?

Or is each one actually waiting for the last to complete before being started?

```
private async Task AddDefaultTasks(Item project)
{
    await this.AddChildAsync(project, "Task A", Enums.ItemTypes.Task);
    await this.AddChildAsync(project, "Task B", Enums.ItemTypes.Task);
    await this.AddChildAsync(project, "Task C", Enums.ItemTypes.Task);
}

private async Task<Item> AddChildAsync(Item parent, string name, Enums.ItemTypes itemType)
{
    return await this.NewAsync(new Item() { Name = name, ParentId = parent.Id, ItemTypeId = (int)itemType });
}

public async Task<Item> NewAsync(Item item)
{
    item.OwnedById = this._applicationUserProvider.CurrentAppUserId;
    item.InsertedBy = item.OwnedById;
    item.UpdatedBy = item.InsertedBy;
    item.EntityStatusId = (int)Enums.EntityStatus.Active;
    DbContext.Items.Add(item);
    await this.SaveChangesAsync();
    return item;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this in terms of async/await, like await all?  (Other than the obvious way of creating all three and saving once). As I understand it, EntityFrameworkCore does not support Parallelism, and in this case, I am using a single context for each HttpRequest.

Comment: No they're processed serially because you await each call. And that's the way it should be because a context isn't thread-safe. But since the context is outside these three methods it can still be accessed by multiple threads if `AddDefaultTasks` isn't awaited by the caller and the caller starts a new operation on this context. Apart from that, it's not efficient and probably not correct transactionally, to call `SaveChangesAsync()` each time you add a new item. The big challenge in using async methods with EF is to make sure that a context is accessed by one thread only.

Comment: I don't understand this: `Since the context is outside these three methods it can still be accessed by multiple threads...` But I thought that async/await does not create threads, so where does the multiple threads come from?

Comment: It doesn't *create* threads, true, but since `Task`s are returned it opens the possibility for a caller to run parallel tasks.

Comment: Speaking about EF Core, `DbContext` implements a mechanism which allows only single active async operation at a time. Or in other words, prevents multiple active async operations at the same time on a single context instance. All that means that `Task.WhenAll` and similar can run in parallel only async tasks operating on a separate context instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the basics and then move on to the EF-specific code.

> The question is, are these actually being processed in parallel? Meaning mulitple threads?

1. No, parallel and asynchronous processing are not the same. There's nothing that makes the previous code run in parallel, in fact, it's all sequential.
2. No, the `async` and `await` keywords do not create nor work with `Thread`s.

As an additional note, you could remove the `async` and `await` keywords from `AddChildAsync`, they are not needed.

If you *wanted* to run your code in a parallel, asynchronous way, you would do:

```
await Task.WhenAll(
    this.AddChildAsync(project, "Task A", Enums.ItemTypes.Task),
    this.AddChildAsync(project, "Task B", Enums.ItemTypes.Task)
    this.AddChildAsync(project, "Task C", Enums.ItemTypes.Task)
);
```

This would start and run all three tasks in parallel.

*However*, `DbContext` operations are **not** thread-safe, and the above code has a high probability of failing horribly.

There are two ways to deal with this:

1. Make `AddChildAsync` spawn its own instance of the `DbContext`. This would allow you to use the parallel code I mentioned previously.
2. Make another `AddChildAsync` that does not save the changes or make it take a boolean for determining whether to save or not. With this, you would only call the database after all three entities are added to the context. This, while sequential, can easily be faster than the parallel processing from the above code.